# Remove inline data-fancybox value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've set up a animated masonry gallery with filters using [this](http://simbyone.com/animated-masonry-gallery-with-filters/) along with fancybox pop up.

What I'm trying to set up is a script that will remove the inline data-fancybox="**gallery**" which groups them together and allows users to scroll through the entire gallery.

When one of the filter links is clicked, it adds a "isotope-hidden" class to the images and hides them however it still belongs to the data-fancybox="gallery" so is still able to be accessed by when the pop up is enabled. I wanted to set up a script to remove this value if a specific class is found on the image.

Here is my attempted script.

How can i remove the data-fancybox="**gallery**" that's in the parent div of the image tag if "**isotope-hidden**" class is added to the image tag?

```js
jq('.filterbutton').click(function () {
  if (jq("isotope .item img").hasClass("isotope-hidden")) {
      jq(".isotope .item .img").parent().attr("data-fancybox", "");
    } else if (jq("sotope .itme .img").hasClass("isotope-item")) {
      jq(".isotope .item .img").parent().attr("data-fancybox", "gallery");
    }
});
```

```css
#gallery-header-center-right{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.gallery-header-center-right-links {
 color: #333333;
 float: left;
 height: 35px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 400;
 -webkit-transition: background 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: background 0.5s;
 -o-transition: background 0.5s;
 transition: background 0.5s;
}
.gallery-header-center-right-links:hover {
 background-color: rgba(63,141,191,1);
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 cursor: pointer;
}
.gallery-header-center-right-links-current {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background-color: rgba(63,141,191,1);
}
.gallery-header-center-right-links-current:hover {
 background-color: rgba(63,141,191,0.5);
}
.filterbutton{
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}
.item{
  width: 320px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
.item img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery">
<div id="gallery-header">
<div id="gallery-header-center">
<div id="gallery-header-center-right">
<div class="gallery-header-center-right-links filterbutton" id="filter-all">All</div>
<div class="gallery-header-center-right-links filterbutton" id="filter-kw17">KW17</div>
<div class="gallery-header-center-right-links filterbutton" id="filter-kw16">KW16</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="gallery-content">
<div id="gallery-content-center">
<a class="item" href="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/a-jordan.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery">
 <img src="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/a-jordan.jpg" class="all kw17"/>
</a>
<a class="item" href="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/a-KWF.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery">
 <img src="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/a-KWF.jpg" class="all kw16">
</a>
<a class="item" href="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/a-KWF2.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery">
 <img src="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/a-KWF2.jpg" class="all kw17"/>
</a>
<a class="item" href="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/a-KWF3.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery">
 <img src="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/a-KWF3.jpg" class="all kw17"/>
</a>
<a class="item" href="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/a-remix-mag.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery">
 <img src="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/a-remix-mag.jpg" class="all kw16">
</a>
<a class="item" href="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/a-sammy.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery">
 <img src="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/a-sammy.jpg" class="all kw17"/>
</a>
<a class="item" href="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/BeautyEQLoveridge.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
 <img src="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/BeautyEQLoveridge.png" class="all kw17"/>
</a>
<a class="item" href="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/kwwomensweekly.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery">
 <img src="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/kwwomensweekly.jpg" class="all kw16">
</a>
<a class="item" href="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/kylie.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery">
 <img src="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/kylie.jpg" class="all kw17"/>
</a>
<a class="item" href="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/myraboot.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery">
 <img src="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/myraboot.jpg" class="all kw17"/>
</a>
<a class="item" href="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/next.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery">
 <img src="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/next.jpg" class="all kw16">
</a>
<a class="item" href="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/nextj.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery">
 <img src="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/nextj.jpg" class="all kw17"/>
</a>
<a class="item" href="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/snuggle.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery">
 <img src="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/snuggle.jpg" class="all kw16">
</a>
<a class="item" href="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/sundaymag.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery">
 <img src="http://develop.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/sundaymag.jpg" class="all kw17"/>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have some inconsistencies in your selectors (item/itme, isotope/sotope).   Could that be the problem?

Comment: @ChavaG no, i fixed that and still no luck. Any ideas?